# How to create a function that the input are two lists and the output are the elements that that are equal in the lists?

Tags: list, haskell

The elements just need to be equal. Each list cannot have repeated elements.

I tried this but somehow the function never hits "length (j:k) == 0 = intersect t (j:k)"

```
intersect _ [] = []
intersect (h:t) (j:k)
 |length (j:k) == 0 = intersect t (j:k)
 |h==j = h : intersect t k
 |otherwise =  intersect (h:t) k
```

What I'm trying to do is like "[1,2,3] [7,2,0] ======> [2]"

Comment: `length (j:k)` is *at least* one, since you make a list that starts with `j` and `k` as a list of remaining elements.

Comment: Do the equal elements need to be in the same position in the lists?

Comment: No, the elements just need to be equal. BTW each list cannot have repeated elements.

Answer (score 2):

`length (j:k)` is *at least* one, since you make a list that starts with `j` and `k` as a list of remaining elements.

In Haskell it is rare to work with `length` on a list, since it takes linear time to determine the length of a list, and for infinite lists, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

You can work with an `elem` to check if an item is an element of a list, so you can work with:

```
intersect :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersect xs = filter (`elem` xs)
```

For two lists with lengths *m* and *n*, this will run in *O(m×n)*, so it is better to work with a collection that can perform fast lookups. For example a [**`HashSet`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.14.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html) of the [**`unordered-containers`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.14.0/docs/Data-HashSet.html).

This will not work for intersections where the first list has infinite length. You can make a function that can yield intersections, even if both lists are infinite, I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: And will be really slow for large lists.

Comment: @pedrofurla: yes, I added a note about time complexity and the possibility to do this more efficient.